# How to share a folder in a asp.net web application with a win form client?

Tags: asp.net, desktop-application, shared-directory

In this asp.net web application, users can upload files to the server through a web interface. All the uploaded files are save in a server side folder. If I want to create a new win form desktop client (actually, its a WPF application) which can be used to upload files to that same server side folder as web interface does, how can I share that server side folder with that win form client? Any alternative suggestions are also welcome.

thanks for all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like answered in [What is the best way to store files in a (asp.net + wcf) web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360925/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-files-in-a-asp-net-wcf-web-application/3360959#3360959):

- Use the WCF tier as a common ground and store the images behind that service. As I said it's going to be an extra to pull the byte arrays over.
- Store the images in the Web UI tier and have a service (asmx or WCF one) to expose the images to your winforms/WPF client.
- Make a share for the winforms/WPF client on the server where the web ui runs, and where the images are. Of course be sure to be respectful to security and possible hacks.

Comment: can you explain more about this third approach? I mean how to do that?

Comment: Simply have a windows shared folder like z:\ to the server. Of course this'll only work for people inside your organisation who have privileges on that server. Not the best option but an option.

Comment: ok, since this is public accessible site, i think its not a good solution. I think best option is second approach for this app.
thanx lot for your support

Answer (score 4):

Several ways; you could consider creating a web service on that same server, and the wpf app will communicate with this service.  Or, if in the same network, it should be able to communicate via a network share, provided the proper permissions are set.

HTH.

Comment: hi, thx. yes, I think having a service in the server will be a good solution. because this app will be host in the internet.

Comment: WCF - Upload the files to/through a service, create clients to the service - one of which is the web app, one of which is the windows client.